# Any sqlite db browser to analyze MediaLibrary.sqlitedb of iOS 5 beta on iDevices

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I want to examine the *MediaLibrary.sqlitedb* file on iPhone which is introduced in iOS 5 ( and replaced library.itdb and location.itdb files of earlier iOS4). Its header is "SQLite format 3" but  SQLite Database Browser can not open it, on other hand, the SQLite Database Browser does open the Library.itdb and Location.itdb files. Any idea? Any other sqlite browser  which can open MediaLibrary.sqlitedb file for analysis?

Comment: Anything in iOS5 is still under NDA so shouldn't be discussed on this site. You should discuss it in the appropriate apple developer forums.

Comment: Did you get any further here? iOS 5 is most likely no longer under NDA, and I assume 6 won't be either when 7 comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLite Studio (http://sqlitestudio.one.pl), it seems to be the only SQLite manager that can read the structure and also values of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes here looking for a tool for Macs (native) that can read the MediaLibrary.sqlitedb database, I can report that I've used the Base application (http://menial.co.uk/base/) to read that file successfully on iOS 5, 6, 7 and 8. (I found SQLite Studio a bit difficult to use).

However, even if you edit the database entries, I believe that some service running on the iPhone will wipe your changes. You have to call some methods in a private framework to make the changes, and keep them permanently.